# How to view error messages generated by dajaxice

Tags: ajax, django, dajaxice

I'm learning to use dajaxice, and I keep breaking things, but since only the ajax parts aren't working properly, the entire site doesn't break and generate error messages, so it's taking me forever to find my mistakes.  Is there a way to track down where exactly the problem lies?

Answer (score 0):

I use [firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) in firefox, in the net tab, the django error messages appear under the response from the server.

Here is an ajax example:

[image]

If django / dajaxice encounters a bug in the code, a http 500 (internal server error) response is generated, which firefug highlights in red. The responses tend to be fairly large and the dajaxice responses are in html but with some scrolling the error message can always be found! I think Google Chrome offers a similar feature in developer tools.

The other handy trick is to use `print` statements in the dajaxice methods, for example:

```
@dajaxice_register
def updateText(request, objId, text):
    print "updateText:: objId: %s text %s" % (objId, text)
    t = TextItem.objects.get(id=objId)
    t.text = text
    print "updateText:: t.text: " % t.text
    t.save()
    json_return = simplejson.dumps({'text': text, 'objId': objId})
    print "updateText:: json_return: %s" % json_return
    return json_return
```

When running the app using `./manage.py runserver`, the print statements show up immediately in the console, interspersed with the network requests to django, if one of the print statements does not apear than code execution did not get that far, or did not follow that branch of a conditional (if statement).

The print statements should be removed from your code once it is working correctly, as they will effect the speed of the app in a production environment. A longer term solution is to use the [`django.logging`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/) module.